# What can cause autocorrelation in higher lag orders of returns?

Tags: arima, autocorrelation, garch, box-jenkins

I am fitting an AR(p) model to the daily time series of S&P500 returns. I have examined AIC/BIC up to 5 lags and both show that model with 2 lags is optimal. However, when I examine the residuals of regression, autocorrelation appears at 20+ lags, as shown below.

What can be explanation for this? VOlatillity clustering/need for GARCH? MA?
AR(30) solves it, but I don't know how to interpret all of this....
I hope that someone would like to help!
[image]

[image]

Comment: I wonder what is unclear for those who voted for closing this as unclear.

Comment: Cross-posted at Quantitative Finance SE [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/38055/what-can-cause-autocorrelation-in-higher-lag-orders-of-returns). Be aware that cross-posting  at SE sites is discouraged.